# Convert from Gen (Maybe Int) to Maybe Int

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I want to convert a `Gen (Maybe Int)` to a `Maybe Int`. I have a function that generates a random Just Int between 1 and 9. I want to use the cell-function but I cant change anything in its type-signature. Any suggestions?

```
 cell :: Gen (Maybe Int)
 cell = frequency
         [(9, return Nothing),
         (1, do n <- choose (1,9)  
                return (Just n))]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are some ways of doing that

```
> sample' cell
[Nothing,Just 5,Nothing,Nothing,Just 7,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Just 6,Nothing]
```

It will generate a list of random `cell`s. You can call head if you want to get only one element.

You can use `unGen` as

```
main = do
    s <- newStdGen 
    print $ unGen cell s 100 -- 100 is arbitrary
```

Comment: It's better to use `newStdGen`. `getStdGen` will give you the same generator each time if you're not careful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`unGen :: Gen a -> StdGen -> Int -> a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/latest/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#v%3aunGen) function for that. It takes a standard random number generator (look in [`System.Random`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/latest/doc/html/System-Random.html#g:2) for ways to get one) and a size parameter (which I think is ignored in this case).

Comment: I cant figure out how to do this. When I try to use only the function cell I get this message: No instance for (Show (Gen (Maybe Int)))
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Show (Gen (Maybe Int)))
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it   I tried to add deriving Show to the cell-function but that didn't work.

Comment: @poolhustler: Are you just trying to test your generator in GHCi? If so, you can just use `sample cell` or `sample' cell` for that. If not, you can grab a fresh random number generator using `g <- newStdGen` or `let g = mkStdGen 1234` where `1234` is some seed number and then do `unGen cell g 0`.